# "I lack the verbiage to sufficiently articulate"

Tags: grammar

I'm writing an (important) letter to someone who happens to be an English major.

Basically looking for a rewording of the cliche

> *"I lack the words to communicate"*

and have come up with

> *"I lack the verbiage to sufficiently articulate"*

But for the life of me I don't know if it's grammatically correct, or sounds good.

Is it ironic that I can't find the words to express the fact that I can't find the words to express myself?

Comment: I wouldn't mention your lack of confidence.  I would write simply what I need to say.  Concentrate on your message!

Comment: Are you trying to impress the person? Annoy them?  Make them laugh? Have you looked up 'verbiage' in a dictionary? It doesn't fit in my opinion. You can test this by substituting the dictionary definition into your sentence and seeing if it still makes sense. I don't think it does.

Comment: "Words could not adequately express ..."

Comment: What is the context? What message are you trying to communicate?

Comment: Cliches are not necessarily bad. A cliche can often be a useful way to communicate an idea in a way you know the reader is likely to understand. If the cliche says what you want to say, use it.

Comment: @chaslyfromUK *verbiage* probably fits perfectly well if the intent is to annoy or amuse.

Comment: OK, so *verbiage* definitely isn't right. Right now I'm looking at "The symbols and ink marks on this page cannot possibly express what..."

Comment: @phoog, Yes, that's why I asked.

Comment: I like *words*, but *vocabulary* or even *eloquence* would be better substitutions than *verbiage*. I also think that *sufficient* is not the meaning you are trying to convey; probably you want a word more like *adequately*.

Comment: "My repertoire of sesquipedalian utterances is insufficient to transfuse to you the essence of my inner substance."  Or, "I'm sorry, but I don't have the words to *really* tell you how I feel."

Comment: The first comment says it best.  Keep it simple.  Gratuitously fancy wording usually backfires, coming across as snobbish or boorish or worse.  It can also distract from your message.  "Symbols and ink marks" makes me think of typography or printing rather than your actual point.  If you want to say that the words you've chosen seem inadequate, but you can't think of anything better, then you can say it in so many words, but you're probably better off not saying it.

Comment: @phoog it is a hand-written letter, does that make it any more suitable?

Comment: @anon not really.  What is your purpose in saying that you are unable to express an idea that you are in fact presumably actually expressing in the letter?

Comment: You still haven't told us your motivation. You ask "Does it sound good?"  What do you mean by 'good'? Do you mean 'educated', 'humorous', romantic? What?

Comment: @chaslyfromUK Solemn/romantic

Comment: @HotLicks  witty.  +1